# Can't a class both be adhering to NSCoding and have convenience initializers in Swift?

Tags: swift, nscoding

```
class GeofencingPackage: NSObject, NSCoding {

let latitude : CLLocationDegrees
let longitude : CLLocationDegrees
let packageNumber : String    

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeDouble(latitude, forKey: Keys.latitude)
    aCoder.encodeDouble(longitude, forKey: Keys.longitude)
    aCoder.encodeObject(packageNumber, forKey: Keys.packageNumber)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    latitude = aDecoder.decodeDoubleForKey(Keys.latitude)
    longitude = aDecoder.decodeDoubleForKey(Keys.longitude)
    packageNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.packageNumber) as String
}

convenience init(attributes: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    self.init()
    latitude = attributes[Keys.latitude] as? Double
    longitude = attributes[Keys.longitude] as? Double
    packageNumber = attributes[Keys.packageNumber] as? String
}
```

In the `convenience init` method i get the error `Missing argument for parameter 'Coder' in call` on `self.init()`

What i want to do is to have class adheres to nscoding, but I also want to let it be convenience initialized with json attributes when i parse it from the backend. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `GeofencingPackage` class defines a designated (= non-convenience) initilizer

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { ... }
```

and therefore does *not* inherit all of its superclass designated initializers anymore. In particular, it does not inherit the `init()`
method from `NSObject`, so you 
have to add it:

```
override init() {
    // initialize all properties
    super.init()
}
```

Alternatively, define a designated initializer instead of a convenience
initializer:

```
init(attributes: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    latitude = ...
    longitude = ...
    packageNumber = ...
    super.init()
}
```